# Talk to C# .net 6 API from android Kotlin based app (SSL error)

Tags: c#, android, .net, kotlin, ssl

Hi so I've tried almost everything I can find so last resort.

Having an issue with SSL error connecting to api from an android app. I can access the API fine from mobile phone browser (swagger) and Postman. But through the app I just receive 'Trust anchor for certification path not found.'

Code below but first a list of what I have tried.

1. Turning off SSL and all Auth on API.
2. Added rule to firewall.
3. Tried sending SSL cert with retrofit using OkHttpClient.
4. Allowing ClearText in domain-config.

Some of these instead caused an 'End of stream' error that didn't even hit the API so unsure which is the worse error.

ApiInterface.Kt

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("User/Signup")
fun getUser(): Call<User>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
            val apiCall = ServiceGenerator.generateService(this@MainActivity).getUser()
        apiCall.enqueue(object : Callback<User>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
                println("yup")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
                println("nope")
            }
        })
```

ServiceGenerator.kt

```
object ServiceGenerator {

private fun generateSecureOkHttpClient(context: Context): OkHttpClient {
    val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    val caInput = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.certificate);
    val ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

    val keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)
    keyStore.load(null, null)
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)

    val tmfAlgorithm: String = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
    val tmf: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm)
    tmf.init(keyStore)

    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.trustManagers, SecureRandom())

    //Finally set the sslSocketFactory to our builder and build it
    return httpClientBuilder
        .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory, tmf.trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager)
        .build()
}

fun generateService(context: Context): ApiInterface {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://192.168.50.41:5000/api/")
        .client(generateSecureOkHttpClient(context))
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
}
```

}

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.50.41</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/certificate"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

As previously stated API seems to be accessible from pretty much anywhere on my WIFI network, so don't believe it is anything with that. Relatively new to Android dev so all the help I can get would be appreciated. Added API code just incase.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://*:5001", "https://*:5000");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "FriendZone.API", Version = "v1" });
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

var app = builder.Build();

var env = app.Environment;

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "FriendZone.API v1"));
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

UserController.cs

```
    [Controller]
[Route("/api/User/")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    
    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Signup")]
    public IActionResult SignUp()
    {
        
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that api is using IPV6 instead of IPV4.  Your code posted is using IPV4.  You need to change the api.  Usually it is the address[] that is wrong.  Index zero is IPV6 and index one is IPV4.

Comment: @jdweng how would that be the case if I can access the API from my phone browser with the IPV4 address

Comment: I don't know the network.  Best to try from cmd.exe >Ping 192.168.50.41 to see if you can find why you do not get a route to the IP.  I had similar issue a few years ago and it turned out to be a IPV6 instead of IPV4.  Why do you say it is TLS (SSL is really TLS)?  The certificate has to be loaded in both the machine and user stores.

Comment: It's 100% not IP I've tried been able to ping perfectly fine and use the API on other devices on the WIFI network, it's only the app that can't seem to get to it.

I've setup a certificate that the app can see, I'm not sure what you mean by both machine and user store though, I'm not really the best at understanding certificates to be honest, so there may be something I've done wrong there but not that I've found.

Comment: Stores are in the USER temp space in same location that cookies are stored.  Net library since version 4.7.2 does TLS using operating system as default instead of older versions of Net that performed TLS in the Net Library. Since OS does encrypt/decrypt the Machine (OS) need to know the certificate. When TLS is negotiated the Server sends a certificate block with names of possible certificates than the certificate names are checked in the user stores for a matching certificate name. The TLS key is never sent between client and server so the key (certificate) must be loaded before TLS is used.